# How can I pass the text on the button which was clicked to another Activity?

Tags: android

I have an array of buttons of size 5 in my MainActivity. I am not creating any xml file for the layout but creating it from the java class itself. I want to go to DetailsActivity (another activity) which has only a textView which will display the text on the button which I clicked in the MainActivity to go to DetailsAcitvity. The buttons have id as 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. The text is "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E".

I am trying to use the following code in MainActivity.java.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    button[i].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clicked(view);
                    selected = button[i].getText().toString();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void clicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", selected);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

i and selected are private members of type integer and string of the class MainActivty.

The following code is from onCreate() method of DetailsActivity.java.

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if(data == null)
    return;
String name = data.getString("name");
TextView name = findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setText(name);
```

DetailsActivity has a layout from xml file.

The problem is maybe somewhere in

```
selected = button[i].getText().toString();
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you able to see any text value when you open the DetailsActivity?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Is there a related stacktrace?

Comment: @RhysP The MainActivity is working fine. But when I click on a button the app crashes. I am not able to see anything from the DetailsAcitvity.

Comment: What error are you getting? Share the log.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using member variable "i" to store your for-loop index. So when you click the button you will be trying to access button 6 which does not exist and I presume you get an index out of bounds exception?

To solve this, please remove the "i" member variable and instead declare your variable "i" within the for-loop itself.

Before:

```
private int i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    button[i].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clicked(view);
                    selected = button[i].getText().toString();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

After:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    button[i].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clicked(view);
                    selected = button[i].getText().toString();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Using this I get an error on i of selected = button[i].getText().toString(); saying Variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: And also my code works fine if I remove selected = button[i].getText().toString();. But according to you it should have given exception in that case also but it does not.

Comment: Good point. Instead of trying to access your button via an array index, could you just cast the "view" object passed by the onClick method to a button and access the text this way?

Comment: Are you saying something like this in clicked() method-> String selected = ((Button) view).getText().toString();?? I have to check this and come back to you. Slow Android Studio.. :(

Comment: Works fine.. But now I am having problem in-> TextView name = findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setText(name); Is this wrong way of getting the TextView from the layout. Maybe as my activity is not main.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Have you tried casting the findViewById result? For example TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name) as findViewById returns View instances

Answer (score 0):

**String letters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};**

**write below code in oncreate function :**

```
    LinearLayout answer_Layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    answer_Layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setContentView(answer_Layout, linLayoutParam);

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam1 = new LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linLayoutParam1.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(letters[i]);
        b.setLayoutParams(linLayoutParam1);
        answer_Layout.addView(b);
        final int finalI = i;
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("item", letters[finalI]+"");
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
**in second acvtivity for getting data :**

    if(getIntent()!=null){
        textView.setText("u click "+ getIntent().getStringExtra("item")+"");
    }
```

Comment: Majority of the code I already had. But the answer seems fine.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reduce code to achieve this. Try below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Button.OnClickListener{

 private Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_linear_);

 //Button intialization in java code...

 b1.setOnClickListener(this);
 b2.setOnClickListener(this);
 b3.setOnClickListener(this);
 b4.setOnClickListener(this);
 b5.setOnClickListener(this);
} 

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v instanceof Button)
    {
        this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class).putExtra("KEY",((Button) v).getText().toString()));
    }
}
```

In Detail activity

```
String value = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY",""):""; //You can get the value.
```

**EDITED**

```
   for(int i = 0;i < BUTTON_LENGTH;i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setId(i);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: What if I have 100 buttons, I am definitely not gonna have 100 different variables and 100 setOnClickListeners.

Comment: You can simply call b.setonclicklistener(this) inside for loop this i created only for demonstrate purpose. My main intent of an answer to pass value.